# I set my data types in pandas , but while convert to pyspark all data go to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to define the data types of my dataframe, so they're good for a table soon...

So when I convert to spark, it ignores the datasource and sets everything to string

My code:

```
BDtable_FINAL = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['0001-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-02 00:00:00', '2021-01-01 00:00:00']})

BDtable_FINAL = BDtable_FINAL[~BDtable_FINAL['data'].isin(['0001-01-01 00:00:00'])]
datainsert = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
dateinsert= dateinsert[:8] + '0000'
BDtable_FINAL.insert(loc=0,column='dateinsert',value=dateinsert)

BDtable_FINAL.astype({
      'dateinsert'  : 'int64',
      'date': 'datetime64'
    })

spark_df = pandas_to_spark(BDtable_FINAL)
spark_df.printSchema()
```

I've tried several ways:

I'm using databricks so I passed the dataframe to koalas and used the native to_spark() function

I've already tried to set the data directly in spark and in the end it leaves everything as a string, always

Has anyone had this problem?

Essa é a minha função pandas_to_spark():

````
# Auxiliar functions
def equivalent_type(f):
    if f == 'datetime64[ns]': return TimestampType()
    elif f == 'int64': return LongType()
    elif f == 'int32': return IntegerType()
    elif f == 'float64': return FloatType()
    else: return StringType()

def define_structure(string, format_type):
    try: typo = equivalent_type(format_type)
    except: typo = StringType()
    return StructField(string, typo)

# Given pandas dataframe, it will return a spark's dataframe.
def pandas_to_spark(pandas_df):
    columns = list(pandas_df.columns)
    types = list(pandas_df.dtypes)
    struct_list = []
    print(columns, types)
    for column, typo in zip(columns, types): 
      struct_list.append(define_structure(column, typo))
    p_schema = StructType(struct_list)
    return sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df, p_schema)
    ```

[![print][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMM7F.png
````

Comment: Hi Guys, i resolved this problem: 


I forgot to infer the schema, it lacked: BD_Table_FINAL = BD_Table_FINAL.astype({...})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved this problem: I forgot to infer the schema, it lacked: BD_Table_FINAL = BD_Table_FINAL.astype({...})